# Castle Windsor ComponentModel AddProperty vs CustomDependencies

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm wondering what the differences are between the 'AddProperty' method of the ComponentModel and the 'CustomDependencies' dictionary.  I'm trying to set the dependency for a property on an component after it has already been registered in the container.

First I retrieve the component from the kernel

```
var registration = container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(component).Select(x =>    x.ComponentModel).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then I'm looking to set a property dependency on that component.  It seems to work when using the CustomDependencies dictionary, but I'm just wondering what the differences are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddProperty` as the name implies **declares** dependency on a property existing on the implementation type.

`CustomDependencies` is a generic way of associating any sort of dependency **values** with the component. Those can be used for anything.

and if you want to add dependencies to a component do it in a `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` (yeah, that's a mouthful)

Comment: So using AddProperty on a component should force that property to be injected with the specified dependency when resolved from the container?

Comment: Ok, I see where the issue was.  The code I was looking at was calling AddProperty and setting the TargetType of the DependencyModel to propInfo.PropertyType (the service type), not the typeof the concrete dependency.  There was already a different concreted instance registered for the service type and it was being used instead of the one I was hoping.

Comment: if you want a particular component use service override